# MySQL Data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, union

I have three MySQL tables which relate to a messaging system. The schema and sample data is shown below for each table relating to my question:

```
`messages`:
+----+---------+----------+
| id | subject | senddate |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  | Testing | 12344555 |
+----+---------+----------+

`message_senders`:
+------------+---------+---------+
| message_id | user_id | trashed |
+------------+---------+---------+
|      1     |    1    |    1    |
+------------+---------+---------+

`message_recipients`:
+------------+---------+------+----------+---------+
| message_id | user_id | type | readdate | trashed |
+------------+---------+------+----------+---------+
|      1     |    1    |  to  | 12344555 |    1    |
+------------+---------+------+----------+---------+
|      2     |    1    |  cc  | 12344555 |    1    |
```

My question is how would I select all messages sent by or received by a user, where the trashed parameter is set to 1, without selecting duplicate messages. For example, consider the following scenario:

I want to get the message IDs for all messages trashed by `user_id` 1, but I don't want to retrieve duplicate IDs (in the data above for example, `user_id` 1 is the sender AND recipient of `message_id` 1. I don't want to return the `message_id` of 1 twice, but want to get all messages for that user.

I think I need to use a combination of `JOIN` and `UNION`, but my brain isn't functioning after a long day of PHP!

Comment: It makes sense to have a separate table for recipients, but why have a separate senders one? This would allow multiple senders of a single message, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Messages can be sent by a user group, and so when a message is sent in that manner, a separate record is entered for each user in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it only returns one row for each message in the messages table...

```
    select * from messages 
left join message_senders on messages.id = message_senders.message_id 
left join message_recipients on messages.id = message_recipients.message_id 
where message_senders.trashed = 1 or message_recipients.trashed = 1 and messages.user_id = <value>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that leaps to my mind is to use a `UNION`d subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages WHERE id IN (
    (SELECT message_id FROM message_recipients WHERE user_id=1 AND trashed=1)
  UNION
    (SELECT message_id FROM message_senders WHERE user_id=1 AND trashed=1)
)
```

Comment: This will return duplicates without a distinct clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got the query in your mind - I'll just hint you can use DISTINCT keyword to force the DB not to return duplicates.
I am sure you can work it out yourself, because self-conclusions work the best.

Also, a piece of advice - always store dates as `datetime` or `date` instead of `int`. You avoid daylight savings time problems and you can use various date functions provided by MySQL.
Dates are saved internally as 4 byte integers, same as `int` fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help, NB. As far as I know, DISTINCT can only be used on one column. Also, the date is actually a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Yep, unix timestamp is an integer, you probably store it as INT or TIMESTAMP. However, DATE or DATETIME is still far better when you want to, say, increase the interval to 7 days or 3 weeks or anything else. You don't have to calculate number of seconds to include it in your calculation. IF you select DISTINCT message_id and join other tables on their respective keys, you won't get duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, give this a shot:

```
select distinct m.id
from messages m
left join message_senders s on m.id = s.message_id
left join message_recipients r on m.id = r.message_id
where ((s.user_id = 1 and s.trashed = 1) or (r.user_id = 1 and r.trashed = 1))
```